# How do I get minted to work in the latest TexShop?

Tags: minted, texshop

I'm using TeXShop Version 5.27 (5.27).

I've got the correct python installed and pygmentize. They are in my path.

The helps I've seen for --shell-escape are not what I want to do. Also, the answers to questions I've found seem to reference older versions of TeXShop.

How do I get minted to work in 5.27? A Macro?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why do you not want to use shell-escape?

Comment: if python and pymentize are in your path you just need to run `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile`  on your document which you can presumably set up as a command in your editor or simply type on the commandline. texshop or other editors aren't really involved other than optionally if you want to set up a menu option to use --shell-escape